# BCP Adds Space In Output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

This BCP Statement is adding a space between my data.  See image
[image: Issue]

This is DDL and sample data - what do I need to change so that the space is not added?  (Empty column)

```
Declare @TestMe Table
(
field1 varchar(20),
field2 varchar(20),
field3 varchar(20),
field4 varchar(20),
field5 varchar(20),
field6 varchar(20),
field7 varchar(20),
field8 varchar(20),
field9 varchar(20),
field10 varchar(20),
field11 varchar(20),
field12 varchar(20),
field13 varchar(20),
field14 varchar(20),
field15 varchar(20),
field16 varchar(20),
field17 varchar(20)
)

Insert Into @TestMe Values
('Blue', 'Red', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Seven', 'Eight', NULL, NULL, Null, Null, 'Pink', 'Orange', 'NFL', 'Size', 'Last')

Declare @field1 varchar(20),@sql nvarchar(4000), @filename varchar(100)
Set @field1 = 'Blue'
Set @filename = 'C:\Test.csv'
Set @sql = 'bcp "SELECT ''one'',''two'',''three'',''four'',''five'',''six'',''seven'',''eight'',''nine'',''ten'',''eleven'',''twelve'',''thirteen'',''fourteen'',''fifteen'',''sixteen'',''seventeen'' UNION ALL SELECT CHAR(34)+CONVERT(varchar(10),[field1],101)+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field2] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field3] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field4] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field5] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field6] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field7] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field8] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field9] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34) + CAST([field10] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34) + CAST([field11] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34) + CAST([field12] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field13] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field14] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field15] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([inventorycode] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field16] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34) FROM [@TestMe] WHERE field1 = '''+@field1+'''" queryout "'
SET @sql = @sql + @filename + '" -c -t, -T -S '+@@SERVERNAME
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with the script.

First, you cannot use table variable with BCP. BCP is a stand-alone executable connecting to SQL server, so it cannot access variables. With BCP you must use regular tables or global temporary tables. I've changed your script to use global temporary table.

Second, in your SQL query you had [inventorycode] field which is not in TestMe table. I removed that and added field17 which was missing.

After fixing these problems I was able to run the script producing an output without the gap column:

```
one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen,seventeen
"Blue","Red",,,,,"Seven","Eight",,,,,"Pink","Orange","NFL","Size","Last"
```

Use code below.

```
create table ##TestMe
(
field1 varchar(20),
field2 varchar(20),
field3 varchar(20),
field4 varchar(20),
field5 varchar(20),
field6 varchar(20),
field7 varchar(20),
field8 varchar(20),
field9 varchar(20),
field10 varchar(20),
field11 varchar(20),
field12 varchar(20),
field13 varchar(20),
field14 varchar(20),
field15 varchar(20),
field16 varchar(20),
field17 varchar(20)
)

Insert Into ##TestMe Values
('Blue', 'Red', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Seven', 'Eight', NULL, NULL, Null, Null, 'Pink', 'Orange', 'NFL', 'Size', 'Last')

Declare @field1 varchar(20),@sql nvarchar(4000), @filename varchar(100)
Set @field1 = 'Blue'
Set @filename = 'c\Test.csv'
Set @sql = 'bcp "SELECT ''one'',''two'',''three'',''four'',''five'',''six'',''seven'',''eight'',''nine'',''ten'',''eleven'',''twelve'',''thirteen'',''fourteen'',''fifteen'',''sixteen'',''seventeen'' UNION ALL SELECT CHAR(34)+CONVERT(varchar(10),[field1],101)+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field2] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field3] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field4] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field5] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field6] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field7] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field8] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field9] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34) + CAST([field10] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34) + CAST([field11] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34) + CAST([field12] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field13] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field14] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field15] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field16] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+CAST([field17] As VARCHAR(MAX))+CHAR(34) FROM ##TestMe WHERE field1 = '''+@field1+'''" queryout "'
SET @sql = @sql + @filename + '" -c -t, -T -S '+@@SERVERNAME
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```